# Shorten multiple lines of setState code in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state-management

This question is just for the purpose of improving my codes in React which currently looks very dirty and unreadable. I have 10-15 forms field which updated once I get values from APIs.

Here is the code from which I did this,

```
            this.setState({smtpServer:res.data.data[0].smtpServer});
            this.setState({senderName:res.data.data[0].senderName});
            this.setState({senderEmail:res.data.data[0].senderEmail});
            this.setState({smtpPorts:res.data.data[0].smtpPort});
            this.setState({username:res.data.data[0].username});
            this.setState({password:res.data.data[0].password});
            this.setState({authType:res.data.data[0].authType});
```

There is also lots more of setState method which I didn't add. This makes my component code complex. Is there any method to shorten these codes.

Comment: thanks for keeping me posted. I will ask this is the respective channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten them by fitting it all into a single object state using setState. First try to destructure your `res.data.data[0]` object in order to handle the individual attributes better:

```
const { smptServer, 
        senderName, 
        senderEmail, 
        smtpPort,
        username, 
        password, 
        authType} = res.data.data[0];
```

Next you can set state in one GIANT OBJECT with each attributes. ES6 allows javascript to use key only instead of key-value pairs when the key and value have the same name. 
Thus: `const objName = {username:username, password:password}` can also be typed as
`const objName = {username,password}`
By that logic you can just setState as:

```
this.setState({ smptServer, 
        senderName, 
        senderEmail, 
        smtpPort,
        username, 
        password, 
        authType});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure the data and use a single `setState` with shorthand object assignment (*i.e. keys are named the same as the variables*)

```
const {
  smtpServer,
  senderName,
  senderEmail,
  smtpPort,
  username,
  password,
  authType
} = res.data.data[0];

this.setState({
  smtpServer,
  senderName,
  senderEmail,
  smtpPort,
  username,
  password,
  authType
});
```

Or, if `res.data.data[0]` has all the properties you want to store in state, more succinctly

```
this.setState({...res.data.data[0]});
```

[image: Edit result spread into state updater]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these calls are happening in sequence, it could be written as

```
const data = res.data.data[0];
this.setState({
  smtpServer: data.smtpServer,
  senderName: data.senderName,
  senderEmail: data.senderEmail,
  smtpPorts: data.smtpPort,
  username: data.username,
  password: data.password,
  authType: data.authType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if there's nothing else in that object, you could just simply do

```
this.setState(res.data.data[0]);
```

or

```
this.setState({ data: res.data.data[0] });
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in a very simple way as below:

1. You can take that data in one variable and then you can assign it in the state.

   `const data = res.data.data[0];`

   `this.setState({...data});`
2. You can assign it directly without the use of an extra variable.

   `this.setState({...res.data.data[0]});`